# APC Uptime is very low

Tags: caching, apc, litespeed

Here is my server information :

- APC Version : 3.1.9
- PHP Version : 5.2.17
- Server : LiteSpeed
- PHP : DSO.
- cPanel : Yes.
- WHM : Yes.

I rarely open my `apc.php`, i usually open it on my peak traffic, about 3-6 times a day.
Most of the time i open it, uptime is low, ranged from 20 minutes to 5 hours. However i've never received any error e-mail such as when my Litespeed restarts by itself.

- APC memory usage is low, 10-25%.
- Fragmentation is low too, < 1%.

Here is my APC settings.

```
apc.cache_by_default    1
apc.canonicalize    1
apc.coredump_unmap  0
apc.enable_cli  1
apc.enabled 1
apc.file_md5    0
apc.file_update_protection  2
apc.filters 
apc.gc_ttl  3600
apc.include_once_override   0
apc.lazy_classes    0
apc.lazy_functions  0
apc.max_file_size   20M
apc.mmap_file_mask  
apc.num_files_hint  1000
apc.preload_path    
apc.report_autofilter   0
apc.rfc1867 0
apc.rfc1867_freq    0
apc.rfc1867_name    APC_UPLOAD_PROGRESS
apc.rfc1867_prefix  upload_
apc.rfc1867_ttl 3600
apc.serializer  default
apc.shm_segments    1
apc.shm_size    512M
apc.slam_defense    1
apc.stat    0
apc.stat_ctime  0
apc.ttl 0
apc.use_request_time    1
apc.user_entries_hint   4096
apc.user_ttl    7200
apc.write_lock  1
```

Is there anything i can do to make uptime longer?
And my other little question is, when APC restarts itself, is its cache flushed?

Comment: Could this apply to you? [CPanel causes apache restart](http://serverfault.com/questions/102648/php-apc-uptime-problem) - APC never restarts itself, it starts with its serversoftware and ends with it.

Comment: I am not sure. How can i know if it is caused by litespeed restart or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After i asked on litespeed forum, it is because my Litespeed seems restarted every 1-2 hours. My hosting said that the reason that LiteSpeed restarts every 1-2 hours is in order to rotate the access logs when processing statistics. Piped logging on my server has been enabled to fix this issue.